# Why updating from behind a proxy results in hash sum mismatch error while direct WiFi has no issues?

Tags: apt, updates, proxy

This has started from Ubuntu's 14.04 LTS version.

I work on Ubuntu at my office where internet works from behind a proxy server.

Earlier, I could just give the usual update commands from the terminal and they just worked.

But 14.04 LTS onwards, it has become exceedingly difficult to carry out even such a mundane task as updating my system.

Every time I try to update the system from behind the proxy, I get errors of 'Hash sum Mismatch'.

But ***interestingly*** (and to my utter dismay) when I connect to internet directly using my mobile phone's wifi, the update works absolutely normally.

I have tried all the workarounds suggested to alleviate the Hash Sum Mismatch errors. None has worked.

I suspect something is wrong with the way our proxy is configured. If not, I would really appreciate a good hand here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the update Debian/Ubuntu will download a list of all the meta-data about a package first, from this URL:

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz

It will contain something like this for every package:

```
Package: aodh-common
Architecture: all
Version: 6.0.0-0ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: web
Source: aodh
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: PKG OpenStack <openstack-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 97
Depends: adduser, dpkg-dev, python-aodh (= 6.0.0-0ubuntu1), python:any
Filename: pool/main/a/aodh/aodh-common_6.0.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb
Size: 17760
MD5sum: 8f0c651bcc7369034fea6c28653f51b9
SHA1: 7fc8dd248a5139f0f7dd3be5a49614c1b9af7186
SHA256: 98cbde3960701b083bc6744cb57fa2b3946d4d5f6c71512e2265f762d4650a3e
Homepage: https://github.com/openstack/aodh
Description: OpenStack Telemetry (Ceilometer) Alarming - common files
Description-md5: 4d4a9638c22eafe95e8cdbfdae651022
```

For this package it will then download this URL:

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/aodh/aodh-common_6.0.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb

It will then check the SHA256 hash of this similar to doing this:

```
$ sha256sum aodh-common_6.0.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb 
98cbde3960701b083bc6744cb57fa2b3946d4d5f6c71512e2265f762d4650a3e  aodh-common_6.0.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Your proxy is modifying the data which breaks the integrity hash check, because the contents have been changed. You should step through the process of running these commands manually, such as downloading the file via your browser and running `sha256sum` on the command line to see the hashes don't match.

Next you should see what is actually different between the files and why. It's possible your proxy is able to determine that the .deb file is an "archive" that uses gzip compression and is re-packing the contents, even if that seems rather stupid in this context it could be used for a virus/malware scanning utility.

Let's assume you have two .deb files, one downloaded via the broken proxy and one downloaded via a proper working connection. You can compare the two by unpacking them and running `diff` on the two directories to see which files (if any) are different. If the diff outputs no differences, then it's likely the proxy is repacking. If the diff outputs something inspect what the differences are and *why* your proxy is making such changes as it's likely a security concern in addition to a usability problem.

Comment: That's what I call 'bang on target' answer. Though I am yet to try out your suggestions, I am sure their outcome will be greatly helpful. Thank you so much for taking time and offering such a detailed help. I will revert with outcomes as soon as I find time to go through your suggestions practically. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, just went through the process. diff is outputting no difference between the hash sums whatsoever. So the proxy must be repacking, correct?. So should I talk to the sysadmin to make the proxy stop repacking the packages? And if the proxy isn't making any difference to the file while repacking, why the mismatch is occurring in the first place?

Comment: There are many ways to gzip/compress data, for example you can do it with a compression level of 1 or a level of 9, among other things, each of them would produce slightly different packed versions of the files.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe check your source list

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Do you get the same error without connecting with proxy? try closing may be configured incorrectly

Comment: Been there, done that. No use. Thanks for taking time to help though.